# Getting data from a Website after Javascript executed initially with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

i am writing my Bachelor Thesis about Sudoku games. For this purpose i need a lot of Sudokus and thought of writing a program to download some.
For the start i want to concentrate on one page:
http://view.websudoku.com/?

the ids of the the td elements i need are 'c00' to 'c88'

I played around with HtmlUnit and found a way to get those elements:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware")
                .setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
String url = "http://view.websudoku.com/?";
System.out.println("Loading page now: " + url);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000);

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        System.out.println(page.getElementById("c" + i + j));
    }
}
```

So this gets me the right elements. The problem is, that the elements content (especially the filled out numbers) are generated by javascript.
The code above only gets the empty fields, not the filled ones since they are filled later.

How can i handle this problem?
I cant find much up to date help to HtmlUnit. Is it outdated? Are there better librarys?